# Kohana framework карта маршрутизации

Tags: php, kohana

Есть ли в kohana framework карта маршрутизации?

в которой прописываются пути сайта как в yii

Comment: Вы имеете в виду application/bootstrap.php ??

Comment: если это то о чем я думаю то это бред

только скачал

Answer (score 2):

Есть роутинг - [Routing](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing)

> Kohana provides a very powerful routing system. In essence, routes provide an interface between the urls and your controllers and actions. With the correct routes you could make almost any url scheme correspond to almost any arrangement of controllers, and you could change one without impacting the other.

Answer (score 1):

Пути сайта формируются из условий указанных вами.

Если Вам нужно просмотреть "все готовые пути" т.е.

> www.google.ru/category/1234,
>
> www.google.ru/category/845 ,
>
> www.google.ru/category/podcategory/98

Используйте котовый модуль `sitemap`.

Условия могу указываться как `application/bootstrap.php` (рекомендуется указывать тут лишь основные принципы для приложения).

Так же условия для формирования ссылок могу располагаться в самих модулях проекта:

```
modules/<name_module>/init.php

    Route::set('<название для обращения>', '<условия>', <параметры>)
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => '<контролер>',
        'action'     => '<экшен>',
    ));
```

[О том как собираются ссылки.](https://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Route)